# What is the replacement of <apex:actionstatus> and <apex:inputHidden> tag in lightning

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, actionstatus

Does any one know that what are the tags we can use instead of `<apex:actionstatus>` and `<apex:inputHidden>` in lightning

I checked Salesforce classic documentation on these tags but don't know on how to use in Lightning.

Comment: if you see the docs <apex:inputHidden> is renders as <input id="theHiddenInput" type="hidden" name="theHiddenInput" />, so you can use this in lightning

Answer (score 4):

`apex:actionStatus` is relevant to `lightning:spinner`([link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_spinner.htm))

`apex:inputHidden` can be replaces with usage of private component attribute